# Excel - Conditional Formatting with symbols

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to do formatting with flag in my table based on the next conditions:

1. Format in Green when I'm above the average otherwize paint in Red.
2. But if I'm above the average but have negative value, still format with red flag.

[see my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zcO9.jpg)

In the example I added we can see that in the CANDY column everything Ok.
In the SNACKS columns everything also OK, but in the DRINKS column OZI & MEIR are in green color although they are both have small values than the average.

How can I do this?
* I need to use symbols (or flags) and not fill all the cell with the color!

Comment: Is your example already made in Excel? If so, could you post which formulas you're using?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can edit conditional formatting just make first "conditional format" by "icon set" of each row then go "manage rules" and "edit rules" and change as photo.[image]

Comment: I already tried this - It will not work if the the average is for example -2 and one user have value of -1, This value is bigger then the average but it is a negative value and therefore I want to symbolize it with the negative color.

Comment: Please re-check your conditional formatting because in my sheet shown is correct.  check first image.

Comment: see my new example and why it is not OK

Comment: Check new photo it working. You should make condition for each row. Upload your file/test file i will check.

Comment: Note that in the second column in your example you have average value of -2,38%. you fill with negative color 2 cells (-3%, -10%) and 2 cells with positive color (5%, -1.5%). But this is not what I want. I must to fill the cell with -1.5% also in negative color because it's has a negative value (despite its value is greater than the average).

Answer (score 0):

It's will not works here, the average is -6.8 and we have value of -3. I need to paint this cell with RED (Because it's negative) but actually it's get GREEN flag.

[SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU6YE.jpg)

[image]